# Does TOR protect privacy of bittorrent clients like Transmission?

Tags: file-sharing, bittorrent, tor

I am using the Tor bundle and its included browser to initiate torrent downloads with the Transmission client included with Lubuntu.

Clicking on a torrent link provides a warning message that external apps are NOT protected by Tor and clicking ok results in normal Transmission start and it begins the download.

I have seen [assertions in another post answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138089/where-is-tor-browser-opening-transmission-from-how-can-i-open-the-same-transm) that Tor starts Transmission using a different profile than the normal `$HOME/.config/transmission`. However, I see no evidence of the referenced different profile on my system ( `$HOME/tor-browser_en-US/.config/transmission`). The normal privacy settings provided within Transmission seem inadequate for privacy according to what I have read. Has something changed in how Tor bundle browser (firefox) interacts with supporting apps like Transmission. Tor bundle otherwise seems to be operating correctly. I asked the question in the post but it was deleted by moderator for some reason not given

Comment: Is the profile there when the Tor browser is running?

Answer (score 3):

TOR was not invented for file sharing applications like BitTorrent. (That may be why your question was deleted or because you already answered your question yourself when linking to the other question.)

If you want to protect your privacy when using BitTorrent use a VPN provider that provides BitTorrent support and configure your client accordingly, or use one of the less popular file sharing applications and clients that try to work around privacy concerns of [public file sharing (see non-public file sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_sharing).